# Change background image dynamically from get response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to put a background image on `div` unsing an image from a `get` request.
I'm using jQuery but it doesn't work...

Here is my code:

**index.js**

```
<script>
  fetch('url').then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data['img-detail']); // this is the img
    $('.fw .fp-ui').css("background-image", "url(data['img-detail']) !important");
  }).catch(function() {
    console.log("Error");
  });
</script>


<style>
      .fw .fp-ui{
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
      } 
</style>
```

Comment: `"url(data['img-detail'])"` - You're including this as a string. If you want to use the *value* of `data['img-detail']`, consider [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): `.css("background-image", \`url(${data['img-detail']})`);`

Comment: use \`url(${data['img-detail']}) !important\`

Comment: As Taplar had pointed out, `!important` doesn't work with jQuery `.css()`. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/opdgn8cv/). And to fix the formatting of my comment above: `.css("background-color", \`url(${data['img-detail']})\`);`

Comment: `"url(" + data['img-detail'] + ")"` or `var url = data['img-detail'];` and `\`url(${url})\``

Comment: Thanks guys, but it dose nt work.. i made a console.log for this and shows: `background-image url(myUrl)`, whitout `: `  why? thanks!

Comment: How are you logging it? Can you update your question with your latest attempt? The jQuery `.css()` method takes a property and a value - it applies the `:` automatically. If you're just console logging the strings, you won't see the `:`.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/vwdLrz3a/

Comment: ohh okey.. thanks Tyler, i supouse i was doing wrong.. now i do this and still not work..`$('.fw .fp-ui').css("background-image", "url(" + data['img-detail'] + ")");`, before this i have statics backgrounds in style tag and works fine

Comment: it will be usefull to understand what kind of img-detail are stored inside `data['img-detail']`

Comment: @Pil This is a complete shot in the dark, but if your image URL has things like spaces or other strange characters, you'll need to include single quotes around it. I.e, try changing this: `"url(" + data['img-detail'] + ")"` to this: `"url('" + data['img-detail'] + "')"`

Comment: thanks Tyles, i try your code and dosen 't work.. the response is this: {

    "img-detail": "https://static.picante.com/images/detail/910.jpg",
    "img-wide": "",
    "img-medium": "",
    "img-tall": "",
    "img-title": "",
    "texto": "",
    "facebook": "",
    "twitter": "",
    "img-v": "",
    "img-h": ""
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `response` is a JSON object, you should rename `img-detail` to `img_detail` and then use it like this:

```
$('.fw .fp-ui').css("background-image", "url('"+data.img_detail+"')");
```

Using `key.some_value` is a basic way to [access JSON data](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-json-in-javascript#accessing-json-data) with Javascript.

Comment: this way the data from json is evalutated as a string, not its content....

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string to the url param but it's not what you expect cause you are passing `data['img-detail']` as a string, not its value, i would try with:

```
<script>
    fetch('url').then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data['img-detail']); // this is the img
        $('.fw .fp-ui').css("background-image", "url(" + data['img-detail'] + ")");
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log("Error");
    });
```

```
<style>
  .fw .fp-ui{
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  } 
</style>
```

**EDIT**

as Tyler Roper pointed out you have to get rid of "!important" cause JQuery doesn't support it, i believe it's not needed

Comment: Thanks guys, but it dose nt work.. i made a console.log for this and shows: background-image url(myUrl), whitout : why? thanks!

Comment: what do you send to the console, witch variable?

Comment: Can you post a sample of fetch result? it will be easier to help